Hello, facing issue while running multi project developed in xtext nature in older version of xtext and xtend in new Eclipse 4.24 on red hat linux
Setup:

Eclipse version: 4.24.0.I20220607-0700
Java version: 11.0.13 (Red Hat, Inc.)
OS: Red Hat Linux
Relevant plugins: org.eclipse.sirius.common.acceleo.mtl, com.google.guava

Steps Taken:

Updated all plugins to the latest versions.
Tried setting -Dosgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4 and -Dosgi.resolverMode=development in eclipse.ini.

Question:
How can I resolve this dependency conflict? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Plugin developed in older version must run in newer version of eclipse

What issue? [edit] your question and tell us exactly what messages you are getting.
